# Can't get Bootstrap close button to show

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a close (x) button in bootstrap that I can't get to show using javascript. As soon as I give it the class name `close` it disappears. What gives?

```
var btn = document.createElement("button");  //<button> element
btn.className("close");  <!-- unless commented out it won't show -->
var t = document.createTextNode("x"); <!-- would rather use &times; but this will work for now  -->
btn.setAttribute("class", "close");  <!-- tried this and didn't work either -->  
cell4.appendChild(btn);
```

for reference I'm trying to apply this class to it from bootstrap

```
button.close {
-webkit-appearance: none;
padding: 0;
cursor: pointer;
background: transparent;
border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Open up your Dev Tools (hit F12) and inspect the element. You'll see all of the CSS being applied to it. That will tell you where your problem is.

Comment: What is your CSS code (not bootstraps)?

Comment: I don't have any of my own, I'm trying to apply the bootstrap code to it.

Comment: could you provide your html and css or a working example of the issue you are having? [js.fiddle is really helpful](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: give me a few minutes to pop it up on there.

Answer (score 0):

Your css class `close` is clashing with the bootstrap `close` class.

Try renaming your css class to something else to see if the problem goes away.

If you still want to keep on using this css class name, you will then to override (or reset) the properties that bootstrap `close` css class implements.

Comment: sorry i didn't mean to be confusing, that is the actual bootstrap class, I just posted it to show what I was referencing since I don't see it listed on the bootstrap css resources.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently when you create a `button` element in javascript it does not explicitly set the type to `button`, you have to add that in yourself. adding in the line

`btn.setAttribute("type", "button");`

show the correct css for the button.